# How jump/get into certain bash point of command history

Tags: bash, readline

How do we get into certain bash' line of command history by referring to its history line number, and then go normally up/down key to o next/previous history walking through ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a numeric argument to the up key to specify how *many* commands to go up. Given a history like

```
...
100 echo 1
101 echo 2
102 echo 3
104 echo 4
```

up-arrow by itself gives you `echo 4`. But (using default `emacs` key bindings) you can specify type Alt-2 up-arrow (providing a numeric argument of 2 for the following command) to get `echo 3` instead.

When you know the exact history number, use history expansion (`!102`) instead of up-arrow to navigate to the desired command.